How about Chinese New Year 春节 - Question challenge week?
Other sites have effectively run a challenge week where regular users have a competition to post quality questions on a particular topic.
I am wanting to find out if our sites community is interested in running a competition for next week to generate some good and interesting questions for the site.
The idea is to have some friendly competition and help promote the site while providing something that is relevant to an event that is going on in the real world.
My proposal is to have a Chinese New Year 春节 question challenge week. It would start from Monday the 16th next week until Sunday the 22nd on New Year's Eve.
Please vote up or down your agreement or leave an answer if you have something you would like to add.

What: Chinese New Year 春节 question challenge week
When: 16th -22nd of January
Challenge: Ask as many relevant questions that are related to Chinese New Year person with the most questions that are at 2 or higher votes wins
What do I win: If we can reach a positive consensus by the end of the week I will send the StackExchange team an email and hassle them for a prize

Remember, you are also allowed to ask questions you know the answer to if they are questions that will benefit the community.

Neat concept - I really like it.

Me too, also the "hassle them for a prize" ahah :D

That's a good idea to make this site thrives.

No hassling needed, we'll happily chip in! The standard prize has been something valued up to $50. We've gone with books as the prize so far, but we're open to alternative suggestions. :D

@Aarthi books sounds like an appropriate prize

@Aarthi Any kind of books?

@Alenanno We generally prefer books that are on topic for the site (to encourage questipons) but any type of  book is fine -- reference, novel, exercise books, etc.

@Aarthi and also xiaohouzi79, I'm not sure I understood how do we determine who wins... Perhaps you forgot a comma or a full stop there... is it just "at least one question with more upvotes" or "who has more questions with the higher upvotes"? From your question, it seems the latter, but I ask to be sure. :) And what if we end up "even"?

@Aarthi I just saw your comment, thanks! :)

Actually, see this blog post instead.

Sounds great. One prize to consider is a subscription to ChinesePod. They have podcast lessons at a range of levels with some good practice materials. I did a quick browse of their catalogue, and found a 3-month basic subscription for $39.
I think that would appeal to a language learner, but what would appeal to one of our experts? Maybe a reference book? Whatever the Chinese equivalent to Fowler's Modern English Usage might be?

As a prize, since it's "impossible" or hard to satisfy everyone, I'd propose this:
Choose any book1 for any price up to a maximum of $50 (or whatever price we decide).
That way, whoever wins chooses something appropriate and we can all have the chance to get what we like but still under a maximum.

1: As long as it's related to the chinese language, of course.

Sounds good to me or the podcast suggestion by @DonKirkby is also good. I think it shouldn't be a problem as long as it comes in under the $50 limit and is related to Chinese learning.
